# is it possible to create a fixture for a body that could be broken by some other body?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, fixtures

I really want to know, is it possible to create a fixture for a body that could be broken by some other body?

There is the example:

- a body with its fixture divided into small figures:[image]
- and what happens after it is hit by another body:[image]

P.s. Are there any programs that could help the process of creating *such* fixture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can do this using  `Breakable` spotted at :

`net.dermetfan.gdx.physics.box2d.Breakable`

The Breakable allows to easily make whole bodies or single fixtures breakable, which means they will be destroyed if a certain force or friction is applied to them.

**How to use**

> A Breakable is meant to be put in a body's, fixture's or joint's user
>   data. A single Breakable instance can be put in the user data of
>   multiple bodies, fixtures and joints. Since this may collide with the
>   Box2DSprite or other classes using the user data, the
>   Breakable$Manager uses a `Function` to access the Breakable in the
>   user data of a body, fixture or joint.Do not forget to set a Manager
>   instance as ContactListener to the world and to call destroy() after
>   every timestep. If the field is already in use, check out the
>   ContactMultiplexer. The Manager does the actual work, the Breakables
>   are just passive data holders.
>
> A Breakable consists of a normal resistance, tangent resistance, an
>   option to destroy its body in case its last fixture was destroyed and
>   an option setting if the body should be destroyed no matter the amount
>   of remaining fixtures.
>
> The `normalResistance` is the force that can be applied to the
>   Breakable before it breaks (inclusive). The `tangentResistance` is the
>   friction the Breakable can bear (also inclusive). The
>   `reactionForceRestiance` specifies the reaction force a joint can bear
>   on each axis. The `reactionForceLength2Resistance` is the max squared
>   length of the joint's reaction force the Breakable can bear.

referred to [libgdx-utils](https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/wiki/net.dermetfan.gdx.physics.box2d.Breakable)

some other good references with good examples [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/10/09/how-to-create-destructible-terrain-using-box2d-step-1/) and [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2013/10/17/how-to-create-destructible-terrain-using-box2d-step-2/)

> for the question `(Are there any programs that could help the process
>   of creating such fixture)`

yes you can easily use **[box2d-editor](https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/)** which allows you to create complex polygons and you can also create your bodies and shapes from your images or sprites check the official documentation in the same page there are several video who explain the way box2d-editor works :

Features:

> - Automatically decomposes concave shapes into convex polygons,
> - Automatically traces your images if needed,
> - Supports multiple outlines for a single body,
> - Supports polygon and circle shapes,
> - Reference point location can be changed,
> - Visual configurable grid with snap-to-grid option,
> - Built-in collision tester! Throw balls at your body to test it,
> - Loader provided for LibGDX game framework (written in Java),
> - Simple export format (JSON), to let you easily create your own loader for any framework in any language.

Comment: Well, in libgdx-utils it just destroys the body not breaking it into pieces(( I need to create a fixture of a body, which could be broken into small figures, not just destroyed.

Comment: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/08/05/slicing-splitting-and-cutting-objects-with-box2d-part-4-using-real-graphics/

Comment: Still, i can not create a fixture divided into smaller figures, which could be moved when a certain force or friction is applied to them. http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/08/05/slicing-splitting-and-cutting-objects-with-box2d-part-4-using-real-graphics/ - is only about slicing, not creating a divided fixture((

Comment: you may find this topic useful http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=836

Comment: That's good, but it is written in c++ so is there something for Java?

Comment: you could follow the concept and do similar , jbox2d is a port of the c++ box2d library  and the classes and method most of them are the same , syntax change from java to c++ , you have instead  of  abject.doSomethink , object<-doSomthinth ...

Comment: there is a lack of java examples when it come to this library , most of them are in JS , C++, Flash, ... and here is the best reference http://www.iforce2d.net/